# Post data to view

Tags: 7, views

If I have a form that posts data to a view page, how do I go about setting the contextual filter in my view?

Here is sample code I tried running but it's not working:

```
$data = 'name=value&name1=value1';

$options = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => $data,
            'timeout' => 15,
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    );

 drupal_http_request('http://www.mysite.com/companylist', $options)
```

Comment: Please provides some more background about what you're trying to do. This is very minimal explanation.

Comment: I thought I was clear sorry. I want to grab the posted data and use them in my where clause (contextual filter).

Comment: Does the form submission page redirect to the view? Or is it submitting with AHAH on the same page? How is the view related to the form?

Comment: I have an regular HTML form that is a post to a view page. I can get it to work with the GET method because the contextual filters grabs the data right from the URL. I'm just not sure how to grab the data if it is a POST. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean you're not using the form API? Why are you using a regular HTML form in Drupal?

Comment: Because when I tried to run drupal_http_request nothing was happening. Is there a special way to run that function? I would prefer to do it this way.

Comment: What were you trying to do with drupal_http_request? Can you describe your situation more broadly?

Comment: Here is the code I was trying:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST might be accessible at contextual filters -> Provide default argument -> PHP code -> $_POST.

Comment: I tried this originally and it didn't work. Then I saw your post and figured I would try it again and it worked. I must have been cached.